# Why is my drop down CSS disappearing, and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is a really strange problem which only affects Google Chrome.

If I have 299 rows in a drop down list, it keeps my custom CSS. However, the second I reach 300 rows all my styling is removed and seems to be set to a default by Google Chrome.

In the JSFiddle page, it has 300 rows, if you view the result, it will have default styling. But if you remove one row, my custom styling will be applied. Why is this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7opd7dm/

Simple drop down element:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierID, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "DisplayName"), "Select Supplier Name", new { @id = "SuppNameDD", @class = "GRDropDown", disabled = true })
```

Comment: I don't have any problem in Chrome version 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit)

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I noticed that you miss a `}` symbol in your CSS code. But for me, styling isn't disappear.

Comment: Really? Even when you remove a line, verry interesting. Could be our browsers, although it is up to date

Comment: I test it with firefox 39 and chrome 44 and it preserves the CSS. I test removing line with console inspector and removing through the jsfiddle code. I can't reproduce. Can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle?

Comment: Interesting - **there is a difference** in the latest Chrome/Ubuntu - the option font color changes (no idea why), here are both selects in the same fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7opd7dm/3/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude That's the thing, the problem is actually there for me in the fiddle. If I remove a line of the code from the drop down, it will change back to my custom styling. This is really odd

Comment: @Shomz Yes, that is the problem I receive. The font colour does change and I'm not sure why

Comment: Yup, very strange... nice catch. Though generally, you shouldn't be allowed to change *anything* for the options because what you see is no longer a group of DOM elements.

Comment: @Shomz Guess I should report the bug to Google then

Comment: Yeah, if you don't get a good answer here soon, it's definitely a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: Google Chrome is a bug per se. When google stops to make some stupid inventions maybe it converts in a good browser. At this time, most complete and powerfull and standard-stricted coding is Firefox.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude We figured that it could be to do with performance, perhaps Google chrome sets the detail font to increase loading times

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, please write an answer when you figure out something and/or when you hear from the Google team.

Comment: @Shomz I just downloaded the google chrome beta for the next version and it's fixed. They must know about it and have a fix for it inbound

Comment: Great, nice job discovering it!

Comment: @AndrewKilburn I'd be tempted to go for a more snazzy JQuery ddl... a la http://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdropdownlist/index.htm

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I found out that they disabled it at 300 options or more.

> We intentionally disabled styling for 300+ options because of a
>   performance issue (crbug.com/500401).

Read about it **[here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339)**

Comment: well thanx for the link but rather a line i needed an answer and m sure there will be any hack or way by which we can give color to option list in chrome..waiting for that :) thanx again for info..

Comment: Well you asked "*Why* is this?", Sadly I don't know how to work around this, yet.

Comment: Well sorry but i actually wanted the solution as i love to work with css and html and found this so.hope you won't take me in wrong way as i don't have much point to spare but for the cost of knowledge i will.. :)

Comment: @Leothelion the upcoming version of Chrome fixes this.

Comment: @TylerH, which one..i mentioned the latest version and its not working in that :(

Comment: See Andrew Kilburn's comment above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917308/why-is-my-drop-down-css-disappearing-and-how-can-i-fix-it/32250541?noredirect=1#comment51752917_31917308

Comment: @TylerH, thanx a lot but i have already read everywhere on question and tried a lot solution but not working and even that question were asked 5 years ago but still in chrome latest version its not working that's why i have started bounty on that..

Comment: @Leothelion Yeah this is an annoying problem. As Tyler said above, I downloaded the google chrome beta and the problem is solved. This means that google know about it and have a fix inbound in the next version of chrome. Download the beta from here: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, thanx for the link..but when they will release in normal chrome? any idea

Comment: @Leo the lion, in the first half of September 2015

Comment: That's great ..ty for info..so finally there is no solution but only bug..hmm

Comment: Ok awarding my points to you but still i did not get for what i bet my point but still thanx for info :)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Intentionally did disabled styling for 300+ options, so we can't reach the answer that way.

**In short i would like to say that you should  use any custom drop down.**

As you are requesting for a solution to achieve, here's the fix
In that case i would prefer you to create a customized drop-down using other html elements like divs and list and take the selected list value. Here i am going to show a demonstration of how to create a customized div. The code has been tested in ASP.NET MVC5 C# and works fine. Post this demonstration here to promote this idea, as this might help anyone like you searching for what to do on cases like this.

in your **some_view.cshtml** add the following to include jquery and styles

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
<!--<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myjquery.js")"></script> in case want this jquery to be external-->
<script>
function my_dd(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.initEvents();
}
my_dd.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;
    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
  }
}
$(function() {
  var dd = new my_dd( $('#dd') );
    $(document).click(function() {
      $('.wrapping').removeClass('active');
    });
});
/** on select take the value to hidden text field**/
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('ul.my_dd li').click(function(e) 
    { 
     var selected=$(this).text();

     /**change label to selected**/
     $('.label').text(selected);
     $('#selected-value').val(selected);
    });
});
</script>
<!--<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/my.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 in case want the css to be external-->
</script>
<style>
*,*:after,*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapping {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.wrapping:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 1px solid red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #366;
}
.wrapping .my_dd {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: -45px;
    right: 0px;
    background: white;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.wrapping .my_dd li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}


.wrapping .my_dd li i {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapping .my_dd li:hover a {
    color: grey;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    max-height:300px;
}
.wrapping.active:after {
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.wrapping.active .my_dd {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
</style>

</style>
    <div id="dd" class="wrapping">Test Drop Down
        <ul class="my_dd">
    <!-- use list or a foreach or for loop to push content to list
      example
       @foreach(var productId in Model.FailedProductIdsList)
       {
      <li><a href="#">@Convert.ToString(productId);</a></li>
       }-->
      <li><a href="#"><i></i>Select 0</a></li>
            ...............
            <li><a href="#"><i></i>Select 300+</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <!-- @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Propertyname, new { @Value = "selected" })-->
```